# amazon ads xml rendering problems

Tags: android, xml, sdk, ads, amazon-advertising-api

I have been able to get the ads to appear from code in my xml layouts but there is 1 issue. The code does build and execute as expected but in the xml editor the layout is blocked by an error that says:

Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.amazon.device.ads.AdLayout (Open Class, Show Exception)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE  Exception Details java.lang.NullPointerException   at android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState   at com.amazon.device.ads.DebugProperties.readDebugProperties(DebugProperties.java:75)   at com.amazon.device.ads.InternalAdRegistration.(InternalAdRegistration.java:52)   at com.amazon.device.ads.InternalAdRegistration.(InternalAdRegistration.java:48)   at com.amazon.device.ads.AdLayout.initialize(AdLayout.java:186)   at com.amazon.device.ads.AdLayout.initialize(AdLayout.java:177)   at 
...

this is my xml layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background5"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


//start button
<Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start"
        android:background="#19d2b2"
        android:id="@+id/start_button"
        android:layout_above="@+id/instructions_button5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

//Instructions button
<Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Instructions"
        android:background="#19d2b2"
        android:id="@+id/instructions_button6"

        android:layout_below="@+id/start_button"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/start_button"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

<Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Gallery"
        android:background="#19d2b2"
        android:id="@+id/save_button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/instructions_button6"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

<Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Scores"
        android:id="@+id/Scores"
        android:background="#19d2b2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/save_button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

<com.amazon.device.ads.AdLayout
        android:id="@+id/adview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="500dp"/>
```

anyone know if there is a fix for this issue or have any more info about what could cause this?

Comment: Maybe you will give some code ...

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me. The xml design editor is supposed to show you how your layout will look. Try emulating your app or connect it to an actual device. it should still work. For the layout with the ad-view,you will always have the rendering problems, though.